# HAProxy TCP session count stops at 400

Tags: linux, proxy, tcp, scalability, haproxy

I am trying HAProxy for TCP load balancing. Connections come in to port X on a single IP, and the HAProxy then balances these connections to a back-end using the "leastconn" balancing method to keep the number of connections even. This is on Ubuntu 10.04 x64.

I've turned up file-max in the kernel config to 700,000. I've turned up the per-process ulimit to about 400,000. I've turned up maxconn in the haproxy config to 200,000. It reports seeing this maxconn fine:

```
show info
Name: HAProxy
Version: 1.3.22
Release_date: 2009/10/14
Nbproc: 1
Process_num: 1
Pid: 1355
Uptime: 0d 4h38m46s
Uptime_sec: 16726
Memmax_MB: 0
Ulimit-n: 400013
Maxsock: 400013
Maxconn: 200000
Maxpipes: 0
CurrConns: 1113
PipesUsed: 0
PipesFree: 0
Tasks: 1113
Run_queue: 1
node: XXXXX
```

This front-end load-balances across 5 back-end systems. However, when it gets to 400 sessions per back-end, it just plain stops balancing, and is just deferring additional connections. I can see this with the "smax" stat. You will note that the maximum number of sessions on each is 400, and the total maximum number of sessions is 2000:

```
show stat
#
pxname,svname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax,slim,stot,bin,bout,dreq,dresp,ereq,econ,eresp,wretr,wredis,status,weight,act,bck,chkfail,chkdown,lastchg,downtime,qlimit,pid,iid,sid,throttle,lbtot,tracked,type,rate,rate_lim,rate_max,
protoa,FRONTEND,,,958,2000,2000,12624,6230219,6445523,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,1,0,,,,0,0,0,406,
protoa,XXX1672,0,0,191,400,,3222,1249403,1286659,,0,,221,0,664,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,1,1,,2559,,2,0,,198,
protoa,XXX1674,0,0,192,400,,3106,1242103,1289247,,0,,178,0,535,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,1,2,,2572,,2,0,,171,
protoa,XXX1707,0,0,193,400,,3043,1266305,1305311,,0,,164,0,492,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,1,3,,2551,,2,0,,161,
protoa,XXX1782,0,0,189,400,,3046,1236790,1282690,,0,,204,0,619,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,1,4,,2429,,2,0,,190,
protoa,XXX1851,0,0,193,400,,3060,1235618,1281616,,0,,189,0,570,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,1,5,,2490,,2,0,,180,
protoa,BACKEND,0,0,958,2000,2000,12624,6230219,6445523,0,0,,956,0,2880,0,UP,5,5,0,,0,17645,0,,1,1,0,,12601,,1,0,,406,
protob,FRONTEND,,,4,6,2000,28,15204,15726,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,2,0,,,,0,0,0,2,
protob,XXX1672,0,0,2,2,,5,2313,2322,,0,,0,0,0,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,2,1,,5,,2,0,,1,
protob,XXX1674,0,0,0,2,,5,3520,3803,,0,,0,0,0,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,2,2,,5,,2,0,,1,
protob,XXX1707,0,0,0,2,,8,3303,3214,,0,,0,0,0,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,2,3,,8,,2,0,,1,
protob,XXX1782,0,0,1,2,,5,3529,3745,,0,,0,0,0,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,2,4,,5,,2,0,,1,
protob,XXX1851,0,0,1,1,,5,2539,2642,,0,,0,0,0,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,2,5,,5,,2,0,,1,
protob,BACKEND,0,0,4,6,2000,28,15204,15726,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,5,5,0,,0,17645,0,,1,2,0,,28,,1,0,,2,
```

Where is this limitation coming from? I really want to cramp hundreds of thousands of connections into this haproxy instance. (The machine has network, CPU and RAM to keep up)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, reading the source for version 1.3.x, I find out that:
There are two maxima.
One is the global max # connections, set with -n on the command line and maxconn in global config.
The other is the per-proxy max # connections, set with -N on the command line, or configured per proxy in the config.
Specifically, you cannot configure the default max # connections per proxy other than from the command line!
The default is ... wait for it ... 2000!
So adding a "maxconn 200000" to each of the "listen" sections in my /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg file solves this problem.

Note that, despite the documentation being pretty good, it did not do a good job of explaining this. Specifically, from reading the documentation, I thought that the global maxconn would be applied to each proxy as well, but not so. The global maxconn is *enforced* for the total number of connections, but the local max number of connections for a given proxy front end has to be explicitly specified.

Comment: I think your answer is a bit confusing. You are saying "you cannot configure the default max # connections per proxy other than from the command line" and also that "adding a 'maxconn 200000' to each of the 'listen' sections in .cfg solves the problem", which seems contradictory.

Comment: "Proxy" and "listen" are different. There are two different maxima. That was the whole source of the confusion.